# How to change figure size that is from the code

Tags: graphics, size

I am using the `R Studio` trying to make a rapport of my jobb by means of `Sweave` file that creates a `Latex` format and allow to make nice documents.
I write my code directly in the `Sweave` (mostly to make a figures) without saving figures to the files and using them to the `Latex` by means of `\includegraphics` function. I use the code as it is below and it gives me the figure to the pdf file. The question is if I can influence the size of the figure that is produced by the code below - I mean just positioning on the page and changing `width` and `height` or place two figures close to each other.
Have no expirience with Latex

```
\section{Resultat}
\subsection{Höjd}
Here I will describe the results about height
%----------------- Figure 1
\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
<<fig = TRUE, echo = FALSE>>=
  setwd("C:X")
  df <- read.csv("X.csv")
  library(dplyr)

  p0 <- df %>%  filter(Fled > 0) %>% group_by(Ovrigt) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(Ovrigt), y = h14)) + 
  geom_boxplot()+
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "point", shape = 2, aes(group = Ovrigt)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  #ggtitle("Medel höjd 2014, Tagel") +
  theme_classic() + xlab("Material typ") + ylab("Höjd (cm)")

  p0
  print(p0)
@
  \end{center}
\caption{Olika material höjd efter en tillväxt säsongen}
\end{figure}

%--------------------Figure 2
\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
<<fig = TRUE, echo = FALSE>>=
  setwd("X")
  df <- read.csv("X.csv")
  library(dplyr)

  p1 <- df %>%  filter(Fled > 0) %>% group_by(Ovrigt) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(Ovrigt), y = h16)) + 
  geom_boxplot()+
  stat_summary(fun.y = "mean", geom = "point", shape = 2, aes(group = Ovrigt)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  #ggtitle("Medel höjd 2014, Tagel") +
  theme_classic() + xlab("Material typ") + ylab("Höjd (cm)")

  print(p1)
@
  \end{center}
\caption{Olika material höjd efter tre tillväxt säsongen}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Your figures look more like source code. Do you know the package [tag:listings] or [tag:minted] to better plot such stuff? Also it is unclear what you mean with "change the size of the figure". Do you mean the font size or what? Please be more specific.

Comment: If it would be a figure, yes, but as I already stated in my first comment, your "figure" looks more like source code. Thus, I would recommend to have a look at the two packages. There you can easily control font sizes, etc. Could you state which (programming) language it is that you have typed?

Comment: Now I am confused: Do you want to print the code or the result of the code? From your last comment I now think the later. Then your question will most probably be off-topic, when you want to size the figure using the external program. To include a figure you can use `\includegraphics[<optional options>]{<figure name>}`. The optional options have keys like `width`, `height` and `scale` to change the size of the included figure. That of course would be on-topic. For that have a look at the package [graphicx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx).

Comment: Then please edit your question accordingly. The answer is given in my previous comment. Good luck!

Comment: Add the chunk options `height` and  `width`  if you are using the Sweave syntax or  `fig.width`  and `fig.height`, `out.width`, `out.height`, `fig.dim`, etc.  with knitr syntax (recommended). You should visit the help page about  [package and chunk options](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/).

Comment: @StefanPinnow That R source code is really the figure (it will produce a nice graph without listing code when compiled) although is not a good MWE  because is calling a external file (X.csv) that is not included in the question, so no one can compile the example to see the result .